# Get layout to display after setcontentview?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So I want my main UI is display before I launch a bunch of asynctasks.  However, in debug mode after the line setcontentview is called, the layout does not show up on the screen.  How do I get it to show up before I run the multiple threads?
The example is below

```
SetContentView(R.layout.main)

//loop and run multiple asynctask threads
```

Answer (score 0):

`setContentView()` is called in the main UI thread. That means that if you are debugging, you block the UI thread and no UI can be shown until `onCreate()` has finished. Move your breakpoint inside `doInBackground()` of the AsyncTask and you will see the UI.

Comment: Ah, How do i call the asynctask after oncreate() has finished?  Right now it is being launched in the oncreate method.

Comment: you create and execute the AsyncTask in the onCreate() method. doInBackground() will then be executed in a separate thread. That means that the UI thread and onCreate() don't get blocked by it and onCreate() can finish.

Comment: The problem is that creating all the asynctask threads takes time, and will block the interface from showing while they are being created.  i want the interface to be displayed on the phone first, before the threads are called.